# Could anyone tell how the code made to work properly?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a code supposed to generate sine wave ? But while running the code I am getting the output in decimal form ,But I need the output as a sine wave .Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try Create Sine Wave</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wave"></div>
<button id="play" onClick="SweepFreq(100,100,500);initSweep(document.getElementById('wave'));"> Start</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SweepFreq(cyc,lo, hi) {
this.cyclesPerMinute = cyc;
this.cycle_length = 60.0/this.cyclesPerMinute;
this.lowFreq = lo;
this.highFreq = hi;
this.time = 0.0;
this.buffer = null;
alert("hai");
window.initSweep = function (element) {
    var sampleRate = 10000.0;
    var seconds = 1;
    var length = sampleRate*seconds;
    this.buffer = new Float32Array(length);
    alert("hallo");
    this.generateSineWave(this.buffer, sampleRate, seconds);
}

this.generateSineWave = function(buffer, sampleRate, seconds) {
    var deltaTime = 1.0/(sampleRate);

    var oldCyclePosition=0;
    alert("happy");
    for (var i = 0; i < sampleRate*seconds; i++) {
        var frequencyFactor = this.getFrequencyFactor(deltaTime);
        var frequency = ((this.highFreq-this.lowFreq)*frequencyFactor)+this.lowFreq;

        var distanceMovedInThisSample  = frequency / sampleRate;
        var currentCyclePosition =  distanceMovedInThisSample + oldCyclePosition;

        var val = Math.sin(currentCyclePosition * 2.0 * Math.PI);
        this.buffer[i] = val;
        oldCyclePosition = currentCyclePosition;
        document.write(val);
    }
};

this.getFrequencyFactor = function(deltaTime) {
    this.time += deltaTime;
    if (this.time > this.cycle_length)
        this.time -= this.cycle_length;
    var progress = this.time/this.cycle_length;
    if (progress < 0.5) {
        return progress*2.0;
    }
    else {
        return 1.0-((progress-0.5)*2.0);
    }
};

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And further more I was trying to generate a sound form from the sine wave , using the audio tag in html5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: All I can tell you is use a *Console*

Comment: *"Could anyone tell why this code is not working?"* Not working **how**? Say what you expect, and what you're seeing instead.

Comment: A more descriptive title may help.

Comment: I've rolled back the title edit by someone other than the OP. It changed the question. It's not at all clear that the way it changed it is what the OP is asking. (It's unclear what the OP is asking.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's interesting to see how people accepts those edits, without bothering to see the edit first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function initSweep is never called. Try this instead (the only difference is initSweep(document.getElementById('wave')); was added to the onclick of the button):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try Create Sine Wave</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wave"></div>
<button id="play" onClick="SweepFreq(100,100,500);initSweep(document.getElementById('wave'));"> Start</button>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SweepFreq(cyc,lo, hi) {
this.cyclesPerMinute = cyc;
this.cycle_length = 60.0/this.cyclesPerMinute;
this.lowFreq = lo;
this.highFreq = hi;
this.time = 0.0;
this.buffer = null;

window.initSweep = function (element) {
    var sampleRate = 10000.0;
    var seconds = 1;
    var length = sampleRate*seconds;
    this.buffer = new Float32Array(length);
    this.generateSineWave(this.buffer, sampleRate, seconds);
}

this.generateSineWave = function(buffer, sampleRate, seconds) {
    var deltaTime = 1.0/(sampleRate);

    var oldCyclePosition=0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sampleRate*seconds; i++) {
        var frequencyFactor = this.getFrequencyFactor(deltaTime);
        var frequency = ((this.highFreq-this.lowFreq)*frequencyFactor)+this.lowFreq;

        var distanceMovedInThisSample  = frequency / sampleRate;
        var currentCyclePosition =  distanceMovedInThisSample + oldCyclePosition;

        var val = Math.sin(currentCyclePosition * 2.0 * Math.PI);
        this.buffer[i] = val;
        oldCyclePosition = currentCyclePosition;
        console.log(val);
    }
};

this.getFrequencyFactor = function(deltaTime) {
    this.time += deltaTime;
    if (this.time > this.cycle_length)
        this.time -= this.cycle_length;
    var progress = this.time/this.cycle_length;
    if (progress < 0.5) {
        return progress*2.0;
    }
    else {
        return 1.0-((progress-0.5)*2.0);
    }
};

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

window.initSweep is not called in your code

The following lines executed in your code,

```
this.cyclesPerMinute = cyc;
this.cycle_length = 60.0/this.cyclesPerMinute;
this.lowFreq = lo;
this.highFreq = hi;
this.time = 0.0;
this.buffer = null;
```

then you have functions declarations that never executed